# base64 is incorrect. how to convert json to correct base64?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, base64

I want to convert this json to base64 using Javascript/Nodejs. But it is not giving me correct output?

My JSON object:

```
const templates = [
  {
    "name": "next-hover-base",
  },
  {
    "name": "next-hover-base",
  },
];

const inBase64Format = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(templates)).toString("base64");
console.log(inBase64Format);
```

It's output is:

```
W3sibmFtZSI6Im5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSJ9LHsibmFtZSI6Im5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSJ9XQ==
```

But when I convert above json object to base64 online from https://onlinejsontools.com/convert-json-to-base64

It's output is:

```
WwogIHsKICAgICJuYW1lIjogIm5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSIsCiAgfSwKICB7CiAgICAibmFtZSI6ICJuZXh0LWhvdmVyLWJhc2UiLAogIH0sCl0=
```

I want to convert above JSON to base64 and want 2nd output in Javascript/Nodejs.

How can I get 2nd output with whitespaces and linebreaks?

Comment: Both are correct. The second one just keeps whitespaces and linebreaks. You can look in the [`space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) parameter to get closer to it.

Comment: How can I get 2nd output with whitespaces and linebreaks?

Comment: I copy pasted your json ( `[{"name":"next-hover-base"},{"name":"next-hover-base"}` ) and got : `W3sibmFtZSI6Im5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSJ9LHsibmFtZSI6Im5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSJ9XQ==` so it's correct

Comment: `JSON.stringify(templates, null, "  ")` should be close. However, I would not recommend it.

Comment: There's really no point in preserving the line breaks and indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one includes a prettified version. to emulate it pass the desired indentation (`2` in your case) to the [`JSON.stringify` method ***space*** argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters):

```js
const templates = [
  {
    "name": "next-hover-base",
  },
  {
    "name": "next-hover-base",
  },
];

const inBase64Format  = btoa(JSON.stringify(templates));
const inBase64Format2 = btoa(JSON.stringify(templates, null, 2)); // 2 spaces indentation

console.log(inBase64Format);
// W3sibmFtZSI6Im5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSJ9LHsibmFtZSI6Im5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSJ9XQ==
console.log(inBase64Format2);
// WwogIHsKICAgICJuYW1lIjogIm5leHQtaG92ZXItYmFzZSIsCiAgfSwKICB7CiAgICAibmFtZSI6ICJuZXh0LWhvdmVyLWJhc2UiLAogIH0sCl0=
```